# ICommand Implementation Question

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I am doing the following [tutorial](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2009/06/15/wpf-and-mvvm-tutorial-04-the-commands.aspx), to learn about the MVVM pattern in WPF.  There's something I don't understand about the following seemingly partly given implementation of ICommand interface.

In the code below the _canExecute variable is used as a method and a variable.  I was thinking it's some event of some kind, but ICommand already has an event to be implemented and it's not _canExecute.

So can someone help me as to what _canExecute is supposed to be?

```
  1: #region ICommand Members
  2: 
  3: public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
  4:     return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
  5: }
  6: 
  7: public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
  8:     add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
  9:     remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
 10: }
 11: 
 12: public void Execute(object parameter) {
 13:     _execute(parameter);
 14: }
 15: 
 16: #endregion
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_canExecute` would be a `Predicate<object>`, whereas _`execute` would be an `Action<object>`.

See my [delegate command blog post](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html) for another example.

Comment: Kent - not a biggie, but you might want to note: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but as far as I know how ICommand is usually implemented and I can understand the tutorial, there is a bug and it should read

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
   return _execute == null ? false : true;
}
```

or perhaps _canExecute is a function object to which a request is forwarded. In that case, the tutorial is unclear.

Anyway, I would consult with the author what he had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think writer of the code wanted to decouple CanExecute logic via Predicate delegate so inheritors of Base Command class can decide wheter or not CanExecute like this

```
class DefaultCommand:BaseCommand
{
    //_canExecute is supposed protected Predicate<string> in base class
    public DefaultCommand()
    {
       base._canExecute =x=>x=="SomeExecutable";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default assumption is that CanExecute is always true unless a bool delegate has been passed to assess otherwise.

Comment: What would be the return type of _canExecute? That's what I'm trying to figure out?

Comment: A boolean (in predicate form) - it'd have to be according to the above implementation. 
It'll be a delegate, e.g. 
bool CanExecuteMethod(object parameter) 
{
  return ((Class)parameter).somethingReturningABoolean;
}